# Design Animated UI android

Tags: android, xml, ui-design

I need to know how to deign this kind of UI in android. In this when we click the red button it need to show the items in the cart.[image: First UI]

[image: After Click red button]

Comment: ExpendableListView?

Comment: Perhaps this?  https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Another option is to use a 'Bottom sheet'